Proving the cut property
Question: If $A$
and $B$
are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$
and $a<b$
for all $a∈A$
and $b∈B$. Show that there is a real number $c$ such that $x < c $ implies $x ∈ A$, and $x > c$ implies $x ∈ B$.
How do I prove this?
My professor hasn't covered this topic in class yet, so I am very confused on how to prove this. She gave us a hint: Set $A$ is non-empty and bounded above.  (To show that $A$ is bounded above, pick any number from set B.)
Can anyone please explain this conceptually and show me how to write a proof for a question like this so I understand?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It isn't possible that $x<c$ when $x\in A$ and $x>c$ whenever $x\in B$ since $A\cup B={\mathbf R}$, so $c\notin {\mathbf R}$.

This makes even less sense after you edited it. "there exists $c$ ... show that there is a real number $c$... "

@SuzuHirose I see. almost everyone in my class has asked her about the question, but she continues to be vague, only giving the hint explained in the question.

I'm not sure what you are asking in this question but the property of the reals which distinguishes it from rational numbers is the upper bound property. For example as you know $\sqrt2$ is not a rational number, but there is no rational number which is closest to $\sqrt2$, since whatever rational number we have, there is always one bigger but still less than $\sqrt2$. Real numbers are constructed from the rational numbers by extending the rationals to a set which contains the upper bounds of any set. This may be covered in your textbook somewhere if your teacher won't help.

Firstly, your statement is wrong(before the edit): If there exists such $c$ satisfying $x<c$ whenever $x\in A$ and $x>c$ whenever $x\in B$, then the union of $A$ and $B$ cannot be $\mathbb{R}$ since $c\notin A \cup B.$ So, the correct proposition is:

If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$ for all $a∈A$ and $b∈B$, then there exists $c_1∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $x<c_1$ whenever $x∈A$ and $c_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x>c_2$ whenever $x∈B$.

I will prove the following and another one is similar.

If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$
for all $a∈A$ and $b∈B$, then there exists $c∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $x<c$ whenever $x∈A$.

Let $S$ be a nonempty set of real numbers. A real number $x$ is called an upper bound for $S$ if $x\geq s$ for all $s\in S$.
Proof: Since $B$ is nonempty, we take an arbitrary real number $b_1\in B$. Then we have $$a<b_1,\forall a\in A$$
Thus, we have shown that $A$ is bounded above and just takes $c=b_1$.
More: Now, I have chosen $c=b_1$, the remaining part is to prove that if $x>c$, then $x\in B$.
We can prove this easily by contradiction: If $x\notin B$, then since $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$, we have $x\in A$. So, we get the following: $$\text{there exists at least one element}\ a\in A\ \text{such that}\ a>b_1, b_1\in B$$
This contradicts to the given condition, so we have done.

I don't think it is "a little bit confusing". It is an error.

@SuzuHirose Yeah, maybe it's a grammatical error.

Sorry I just realized I was missing a part. I just edited the question.

@LorenaAlvarado You should check with your professor rather than asking here.

@LorenaAlvarado This statement makes sense.

It is not a grammatical error.

So does the explanation you gave me work when adding the statement? @BoweiTang

@SuzuHirose unfortunately my professor is not very helpful, she is very vague when you ask questions.

@LorenaAlvarado Absolutely, I'll add more details.

@LorenaAlvarado Updated.

@BoweiTang Thank you so so much. Would you be able to explain what theorems or direct me the name of the theorems used to solve this?

The question asking you to prove that a set of real numbers has an upper bound doesn't seem to make sense. This is the definition of the real numbers.

@LorenaAlvarado Just use the definition I listed above.

The fact that there is a real upper bound of any set of real numbers is the defining property of the real numbers. This answer seems to consist of a circular argument at best.
